# Google play error: You have an open-alpha testing program; you cannot manage beta testing users while you have an open-alpha

Tags: google-play

I am having a strange error on google-play for an open alpha-channel alongside an open beta

```
You have an open-alpha testing program; you cannot manage beta testing users while you have an open-alpha.
```

The beta was closed once - perhaps this is a google-play bug? But I did not find this error-message anywhere

Comment: Did you find anything? I get the same error, without even having open beta. When I change the testing method, this error message shows up: "You have an open-alpha testing program, you cannot manage beta testing users while you have an open-alpha"

My alpha testers can access the link to become testers, but the app does not appear in the play store. And there are several hours since it is released.

Comment: I am also seeing this problem without having a Beta open.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an Beta testing method selected, you can't select an Alpha testing method.  I've resolved this issue by doing the following:

- In [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/), Go to *Release Management* > *App Releases* and Click `Manage Beta`
- Under *Manage testers* there is probably a method selected even though you necessarily don't have a Beta release anymore.
- Click `Disable Beta Testing` and then `Save`.

[image: Disable Beta testing]

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but I really wonder why you cannot use both - because then it makes no real sense to have 2 tracks when you can only use one ..

Comment: @ligi No idea, I think it just isn't supported (yet?). For example, when I submit an open Alpha release to the Play Store it still is "branded" as a Beta. At least in my language.